# Phpunit-Selenium runs all assert functions

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit, browser-testing

I want to write some browser tests using phpunit-selenium, Now this is my test class

```
<?php

namespace Tests\System;

use Tests\TestCase;

class LoginTest extends TestCase
{

    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function showLoginPage()
    {
        $this->url('/');
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

And this is the testCase class that i have made to add extra methods and properties to it

```
<?php

namespace Tests;
require_once dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use PHPUnit\Extensions\Selenium2TestCase;

class TestCase extends Selenium2TestCase {

    public function setUp(): void
    {
        $config = new \Config('test');
        $this->setDesiredCapabilities([
            'chromeOptions'=>['w3c' => false, "args"  => [
                '--no-sandbox',
                '--disable-gpu',
                '--headless',
                '--verbose',
                '--whitelisted-ips='
            ]]]);
        $this->setHost('localhost');
        $this->setPort(4444);
        $this->setBrowserUrl('http://localhost/');
        $this->setBrowser('chrome');
        $this->shareSession(true);
    }

}
```

Now when i run vendor/bin/phpunit it runs around 366 tests. But they are not tests, They are methods in the assert class. For example it runs this methods

```
Tests\System\LoginTest::objectHasAttribute
Tests\System\LoginTest::classHasStaticAttribute
Tests\System\LoginTest::classHasAttribute
```

What did i understand from that response is that, Somehow it not understand to run only those methods which has @test annotation or has prefix test. And the final file is phpunit.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit bootstrap="tests/bootstrap.php"
         backupGlobals="false"
>

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="PHPUnit">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">Tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

</phpunit>
```

I appreciate any help, Thanks.

Comment: What package versions do you use, especially PHPUnit and Selenium extension?

Comment: I encountered the same problem with phpunit 9.5.4, phpunit-selenium 9.0.0 and php 7.4.21

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was using phpunit 9.5.4 and phpunit-selenium 9.0.0.

Apparently phpunit-selenium is not compatible with phpunit >= 9.4.0. There is an open issue for this: https://github.com/giorgiosironi/phpunit-selenium/issues/453

So the solution (for me) was to downgrade phpunit to 9.3.x:

```sh
composer require --dev phpunit/phpunit:9.3.*
```

Apparently the same problem also occurs for phpunit 8.5.9: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/4516